# In what way can you interrupt Angular navigation events?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, navigation, flow-control

**Background**
My team is working on an Angular application that has a long-running process - the details of this process are thoroughly unimportant to this question - that can be triggered from one of its screens.  Because of the nature of this process, one of our business rules is that, once this process is triggered, we want to prevent our end-users from navigating away from the page to the best extent possible.

**What we've tried**
In our component, we've tried two approaches: `@HostListener('window:unload')` event interception, and Angular's `Router.events` interception.  Neither has proven successful.

For the `@HostListener()` approach, we implemented the following method in the body of the component, but as far as we could tell, it never actually fired, let alone stopped any navigation.  It's also logical that it wouldn't, since window unload events would apply more to someone manually changing the window URL, or closing the current tab.  It's probably a necessary part of implementing our business rule, for handling those specific cases.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
preventOffNavigation($event: any) {
    // Do not stop off navigation if the special process isn't running.
    if (!this.isProcessInProgress)
        return $event.returnValue = true;

    // ...Otherwise, disrupt the navigation.
    $event.returnValue = false;  // Could we also do something like $event.stopPropagation()?
}
```

The other thing is a little more mainstream - we subscribe to the `Router.events` stream, and when we detect a `NavigationStart` while the process is running, we...well, we don't actually know how we'd stop a navigation in process.  When we inspected the event, there were no methods - it seemed purely informational.  Under the `.extras` property, there was a status property that we tried assigning `NavigationCancel`, but that had precisely no effect.

```
constructor(
  // Other imports aren't necessary for the context of this question
  private router: Router
) {
  this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart
    )
    .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
      if (!this.isProcessInProgress)
        return;

      const currentNavigation = event.getCurrentNavigation();
      if (!currentNavigation)
        return;

      // Didn't work, but worth a shot!
      currentNavigation.extras.status = NavigationCancel;
    });
}
```

**Question**
Our team really needs to keep our end users on a screen for our critical business process, but Angular doesn't provide a visible way to temporarily arrest navigation in its router system.  Are we missing something?  In what way can we prevent Angular from making router system navigations while our process is happening?

Comment: Have you tried a router guard instead? Something like the CanDeactivate guard? https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate or this if you want functional guards: https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivateFn